# 1 function+Multiple parameters // Multiple functions+ 1 parametre by function JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

Which option is the best?

Use a single function with many parameters or call at the same function several times and pass a single parameter.

Example:

```
function exampleA(w,x,y,z){
                document.getElementById(w).style.display="none";
                document.getElementById(x).style.display="none";
                document.getElementById(y).style.display="none";
                document.getElementById(z).style.display="none";
            }

OR

exampleA(w)
exampleA(x)
exampleA(y)
exampleA(z)
```

I just want to know your opinion

Comment: What criteria are you using to determine “best”?

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for clean and elegant code, try this:

```
const exampleA = id => document.getElementById(id).style.display="none"
[w, x, y, z].map(exampleA)
```